# A diagram is a functor

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to understand the definition of diagrams as functors in category theory. [Following nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/diagram), a diagram $D$ of shape $\mathcal I$ in category $\mathcal C$ is a functor $D:\mathcal I\rightarrow \mathcal C$, where $\mathcal I$ is a small category. Let's consider the following cospan:

$$\begin{array}{} && X \\ && \big\downarrow{g} \\  Y & \underset{f}\longrightarrow & Z \end{array}$$

Let $D$ be a functor that maps $X\mapsto C,Y\mapsto C,Z\mapsto C',f\mapsto h,g\mapsto h$ and identities in the obvious way. This yields the following diagram in $\mathcal C$:

$$C\underset{h}\longrightarrow C' $$

Identities are preserved, and there are no composites. We have $$D(f:Y\rightarrow Z)=D(f):D(Y)\rightarrow D(Z)=h:C\rightarrow C'$$ and $$D(g:X\rightarrow Z)=D(g):D(X)\rightarrow D(Z)=h:C\rightarrow C'$$ as required.

Still, this functor does not preserve the shape of $\mathcal I$. It is no longer a cospan. Or is there some other sense in which the diagram $D$ has the shape of $\mathcal I$?

Comment: Surely it yields the diagram \begin{array}{} && C \\ && \big\downarrow{h} \\  C & \underset{h}\longrightarrow & C' \end{array}?

Comment: So I guess the answer is that, via this definition of diagram, we also obtain "degenerate" cases like the one you describe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does have the required shape:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
     @. C\\
    @. @VV h V\\
    C @>>h> C'
\end{CD}

You can think of an indexed family $\{x_i\}_I$, which is a function $x\colon I\to X$. Let's say $I = 2$ and you have $x\colon 2\to X$. Then, $\{x_0,x_1\}_2$ is a family indexed by $2$ even when $x_0 = x_1$.

It's the same with the above diagram, it is indexed by $\mathcal I$ even though the arrows are the same morphism.

Actually, such diagrams are useful. One example is that you can say $h$ is monomorphism if and only if

\begin{CD}
    C @>\operatorname{id}_C>> C\\
    @V \operatorname{id}_C V V @VV h V\\
    C @>>h> C'
\end{CD}

is Cartesian square (pullback).

Comment: Thank you Ennar. If you could only elaborate a bit on the conditions required for the behavior that 'actually' (vague, I know) preserves the shape of $\mathcal I$? I am thinking that if $D$ is injective on arrows, this will do. But this is an 'evil' property; on the other hand, faithfulness appears too weak. Is there a 'good' category-theoretic way of expressing my intuitive idea?

Comment: @Dawid K, this functor $D$ is faithfull, so faithfullness is not enough. You do need some "evil" property to hold. But what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I don't have specific applications on my mind. I was reading a blog entry (http://www.math3ma.com/mathema/2018/1/10/a-diagram-is-a-functor) and noticed that all examples given by the author are injective on arrows. The question that popped into my mind was whether there is a 'good' CT way to differentiate her examples from 'counter-examples' such as the one given in the OP. If it must be evil, then this answers my doubts.

Comment: Also, can we say that the diagram $$C\rightarrow C'$$ has "the same shape" as the diagram $$C\rightarrow C' \leftarrow C$$? If yes, the concept of "shape" appears murky; if not, the how do we tell the difference in a 'good' CT way?

Comment: @DawidK both of those things which you drew are "shapes" in C. We can construct trivial functors f and g from 2 appropriate categories trivial categories, say F with 2 distincts elements and 1 non trivial arrow, and G with 2 distincts elements and 2 non trivial arrows. But you can also create a functor from G to C representing the first shape, by precomposing f with the functor that maps the 2 arrows of G to the 1 arrow of F. So you can have different functors, leading to the same shape. Note however that F/f is final such functor in the category of functors yielding this shape..

Answer (score 0):

A functor $I \to C$ clearly maps to some shape of $I$ in $C$ : just draw, in $C$, where each object and morphism goes. Here is your shape. You might loose information, just like a function always "loose" information, but the picture you get **respects** (and not preserve) the structure you had in $I$.

One way it maximally does not preserve the structure (yet still respects it in the destruction) is in the functor mapping any category to the $1$ category.

By the way, you want to loose information, otherwise, you would have little choice. or you could not be amazed when you have functor which actually is an isomorphism when it's not evident it preserve information ;)

Conversely, a shape in $C$ is also "a" functor, from the trivial category made of your shape.

But, precomposition with any functor (full and surjective) on objects will also yield the same shape.

So there are infinitely many such functors, but they all will factor out through this terminal functor, which starts from the "trivial" category, which looks like the drawn shape and only has that, and goes to $C$, which might have many more objects and morphisms.